# Def function does not work with plotly Python

Tags: python, function, plotly

I'm trying to def a functin but i can't call it:

```
  def test():
      fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[
      [{'type': 'scatter'}, {'type': 'table'}]]
                      , shared_xaxes=True,
                      horizontal_spacing=0.05, 
                      vertical_spacing=0.05,  
                      column_widths=[0.7, 0.3])
      pass

  test()

  fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
            open=df['Open'],
            high=df['High'],
            low=df['Low'],
            close=df['Close'],
            increasing_line_color = UP_CANDLE,
            decreasing_line_color = DW_CANDLE),row=1,col=1)
```

When I call it I retrieve the following error: NameError: name 'fig' is not defined
If I remove the function, the code works perfectly.

Comment: Indentation of your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your local variable `fig` is inside the function, nothing outside of the function `test` will have access to fig unless you return fig from the function – you can read about [scope](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#understanding-scope) in python.

I would rewrite your function like this (and `pass` doesn't have any purpose in your function so I removed it):

```
def test():
    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=1, cols=2, 
        specs=[[{'type': 'scatter'}, {'type': 'table'}]], 
        shared_xaxes=True, 
        horizontal_spacing=0.05, 
        vertical_spacing=0.05,  
        column_widths=[0.7, 0.3]
    )
    return fig
```

Then you can set a variable equal to what your function returns:

```
fig = test()
```

And then you'll be able to access the `.add_trace` method of `fig

```
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
        open=df['Open'],
        high=df['High'],
        low=df['Low'],
        close=df['Close'],
        increasing_line_color = UP_CANDLE,
        decreasing_line_color = DW_CANDLE),row=1,col=1)
```

Comment: More compactly, `test().add_trace(...)`

Comment: Sure - that's the way I would probably write it myself - but I feel like this more expanded out version might be easier for the person who asked the question to understand

Comment: Agreed. That's why it belongs in a comment and not the answer